# Is it possible to get the configured OAuth2 scopes of an invoked endpoint in a WSO2 custom handler?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have implemented a custom WSO2 handler to validate an externally generated JWT token that contains, among other things, the user scopes.

During the handler execution I want to add another check: get the scope/scopes associated to the currently executed endpoint and validate that the JWT token contains at least one of those scopes:

For instance:

**JWT payload**

```
user: xxx, scopes: ["write", "read"]
```

**Endpoint config in WSO2 API Publisher**

```
POST /customers  - scope: write
```

==> JWT.getScopes() -> should contain write.

**How can I get the scope/scopes of the currently executed endpoint in the custom handler?**

**Handler**

```
public class JwtAuthHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {

        //GET the scopes (write) of the currently invoked endpoint
```